# Dictionary and List

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, indexing

While reading through a file I convert the given data in a format of key and value. (value is just age of a person)

For example if file has data:

```
20120101,56years
20120102,45years
20120103,67years
20120104,38years
```

.. and so on until `20120131,21years`.

I create a dictionary and make the date as the key ( in this case let's say line `1`, so the key will be `20120101` ) and i make the value `56years`.

When i print this out, i get a separate dictionary for every date.
For example:

```
{'20120101': ['56years']}
{'20120102': ['45years']}
{'20120103': ['67years']}
{'20120104': ['38years']}
```

Since i see that every dictionary has the same starting values like `201201`,
how can I make a single dictionary that has this one key `201201` and all the values appended to it in a list?

Example:

```
{'201201': ['56years', '45years', '67years', '38years'...]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
```

Now, when you get your key `k` and value `v`

```
d[k].append(v)
```

After adding the first key,value pair, your dictionary might look like:

```
{'201201' : [56years]}
```

After reading a key,value pair where the key is "201201" and adding the value to `d`, your dictionary will look like:

```
{'201201' : [56years,45years]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?(First you need put all of the dicts into a list like the example):

```
d = {}

a = [
    {'20120101': ['56years']},
    {'20120102': ['45years']},
    {'20120103': ['67years']},
    {'20120104': ['38years']},
    {'20120201': ['31years']},
    {'20120202': ['32years']},
    {'20120203': ['12years']}]

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        try:
            d[j[:6]].append(*i[j])
        except KeyError:
            d[j[:6]] = i[j]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'201201': ['56years', '45years', '67years', '38years'],              
 '201202': ['31years', '32years', '12years']}
```